# How to compare two css files and copy just the differences?

Tags: html, css, file, web

I have some css files and I want to compare and copy the different information in another file ?
is any way to do that ?

For example: I have the css file named a.css and b.css and what is different in that two I want to copy in another file, or just to 'auto select' all that information that are different

thanks

Comment: What you are looking for is a [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) tool, refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool) for a list of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using diff

If you are on OS X or LInux, type:

```
diff file1.css file2.css > cssdiff.patch
touch diff.css
patch diff.css cssdiff.patch
```

Comment: thanks...yes I use os x
but .. how I copy the different information in a new file ?
or to select all that different info ?

Comment: this does not take into consideration if the files' lines are not ordered the same.

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can use windiff.exe

You can find information about it here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/159214